# C# connection string in web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, web-config, connection-string

In my code behind page, how do I access the connection string which is stored in my web.config file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YouConnStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

This requires references to System.Configuration.dll and System.Web.dll.

Comment: Shouldn't this be System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings...

Comment: This gives me an error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection'`
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but my guess would be you are not using System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString; or maybe a stretch is you need to reference system.configuration? You get that error because the collection you are using doesn't implement IList and probably only implements IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4):

[How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From comment on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

```
string c = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstringname"].ConnectionString;
```

Requires your project to reference to System.Web and System.Configuration. I had to actually add a reference to "System.Configuration" not just add a Using.